# groupby and count values when column contains list of values with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame looks like:

```
title     type      country    release_year
 a        movie      USA       2018
 b        movie      USA,UK    2018
 c        movie      USA       2018
 d        movie      UK        2018
 e        movie      USA       2019
 f        movie      UK        2019
```

I want to count per country how many movies were released by year. Therefore I'm applying the following:

```
result = df.groupby(['release_year', 'country'])['country'].count().reset_index(name='counts')
```

and this is what I´m getting:

```
release_year     country       counts
2018              USA           2
2018              USA,UK        1
2018              UK            1
2019              USA           1
2019              UK            1
```

However, I would like to get something where USA,UK is counted once under USA and UK and not separate like:

```
release_year     country       counts
2018              USA           3
2018              UK            2
2019              USA           1
2019              UK            1
```

I've tried before grouping as well:

```
pd.Series(df.country.str.split(', ').sum()).value_counts()
```

which gives me the result per country, but not grouped by release_year. I couldn't match both conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `str.split` and `explode` then `groupby`:

```
(df.assign(country=df.country.str.split(',\s*'))
   .explode('country')
   .groupby(['release_year','country']).size()
   .reset_index(name='counts')
)
```

Output:

```
   release_year country  counts
0          2018      UK       2
1          2018     USA       3
2          2019      UK       1
3          2019     USA       1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.explode(...)` for your purpose:

```py
df["country"]=df["country"].str.split(",")
df=df.explode("country")
```

Outputs:

```py
  title   type country release_year
0     a  movie     USA         2018
1     b  movie     USA         2018
1     b  movie      UK         2018
2     c  movie     USA         2018
3     d  movie      UK         2018
4     e  movie     USA         2019
5     f  movie      UK         2019
```

Comment: Thanks! It is similar to the solution proposed by @quanghm, however his solution includes de groupby and size which is perfect.